# norms of operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compact-operators

I am stuck on a question on the operator norm. If $L$ is a bounded linear operator $L:H\rightarrow H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space. How would you show that $$\|L\|\leq \sup_{\|u\|=\|v\|=1}(Lu,v)$$
any hints?
Thanks,

Comment: Is it $|<Lu,v>|$ or $<Lu,v>$?

Comment: @science : doesn't matter, the sup is the same for both (you can take the opposite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : $$\sup_{\|u\|=\|v\|=1} (Lu,v) \geq \sup_{\|u\|=1} (Lu, \frac{Lu}{\|Lu\|})$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** if $A \subseteq B \subseteq \Bbb R$, $A$ is non-empty, and $B$ is bounded above, then
$$
\sup(A) \leq \sup(B)
$$